# How to check if a read-only file exists

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, readonly

I'm looking for a way to check for a read-only file's existence without opening it. I've tried:

```
if (std::filesystem::exists("C:\\Windows\\System32\\hal.dll")) {
    std::cout << "Exists" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Does not exist" << std::endl;
}
```

But it returns "does not exist". I'm looking for a solution that can check the existence of files like these.

Comment: And *why* are you checking if the file exists?  Quite often, that check is both useless and a [TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).

Comment: I just thought it would be a good example. It can be also any other file that is read-only.

Comment: On Unix systems, `stat()` and `access()` comes to mind.

Comment: @JesperJuhl [`stat()` exists on Windows, too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=msvc-170).

Comment: @johnrollins And how will you know it's read-only?  Replicate all the OS-required permissions checks?

Comment: Does the user account with which you are executing the program have sufficient priviledges to read the directory ``C:\Windows\System32\``? Does the problem disappear if you run the program with administrative priviledges?

Comment: Are you sure that Windows is installed on ``C:\Windows\``? I believe it is possible for Windows to be installed on a different drive, for example on ``D:\Windows\``.

Comment: Since this is very puzzling, I suggest that you post a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. Maybe the problem is in the code that you are not showing us.

Comment: Open File Explorer and navigate to the folder.  If it shows the file, there should be a way to do it.  If it gives you an error, you have your answer.

Comment: Checking for file existence without opening it is just a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) race. There's practically no reason to ever want to do that.

Comment: `std::filesystem::exists()` should not have problems with read only files. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Warning: Windows plays very interesting games with the system32 folder to make 32 bit programs in an otherwise 64 bit world run as seamlessly as possible. For example, when the 32 bit program goes looking in system32 it's queries get redirected to sysWOW64.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you so much all I had to do was to change x86 to x64 in visual studio.

Answer (score 4):

`std::filesystem::exists()` works fine. But, you might not be querying the file you are expecting.

First, not everyone installs Windows at `C:\Windows`, so you should ask the OS where it is actually installed, by using [`GetWindowsDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getwindowsdirectoryw), [`SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_WINDOWS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw), or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Windows)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath), eg:

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

fs::path getWindowsPath() {
    WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetWindowsDirectoryW(szPath, MAX_PATH);
    return szPath;

    // or equivalent...
}
```

Second, on 64-bit Windows systems, if a 32-bit app running inside the WOW64 emulator tries to access the 64-bit `%WINDIR%\System32` folder, by default the access will get redirected to the 32-bit `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64` folder instead, which could explain why your `exists()` check is not working.

To access the 64-bit `System32` folder when running under WOW64, you have to either:

- use the special `SysNative` alias, eg:

```
bool isWow64() {
    #ifdef _WIN64
    return false;
    #else
    BOOL bIsWow64 = FALSE;
    return IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64) && bIsWow64;
    #endif
}

fs::path getSystemPath() {
    if (isWow64()) {
        return getWindowsPath() / "SysNative";
    }
    else {
        return getWindowsPath() / "System32";

        /* alternatively:

        WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH] = {};
        GetSystemDirectoryW(szPath, MAX_PATH);
        return szPath;

        or equivalent...
        */
    }
}

...

if (std::filesystem::exists(getSystemPath() / "hal.dll")) {
    std::cout << "Exists" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Does not exist" << std::endl;
}
```

- disable the redirection temporarily by using the [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection) function, eg:

```
fs::path getSystemPath() {
    return getWindowsPath() / "System32";
    // or equivalent ...
}

...

PVOID oldValue = NULL;
if (isWow64()) {
    Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&oldValue);
}

if (std::filesystem::exists(getSystemPath() / "hal.dll")) {
    std::cout << "Exists" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Does not exist" << std::endl;
}

if (isWow64()) {
    Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(oldValue);
}
```

See [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) on MSDN for more details.

Answer (score -1):

If in Windows, function [GetFileAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesw) returns attributes if the file is there without opening. On error, it returns INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES and then you can check with GetLastError().

If you are checking in order to open it later, this can lead to a race condition ([TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) as mentioned).

Besides that, there do exist reasons to check for the file existance without planning to open it, for example for an installer to see if the file to be replaced is there and warn the user.

Comment: Related reading: [Why is GetFileAttributes the way old-timers test file existence?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071023-00/?p=24713)